# I've refused to help the captain in Flotsam and he took my swords?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I've refused to  help the captain in Flotsam and he took my swords? I was then beat to death by some people of Flotsam and I couldn't do anything against it because they have weapons and I don't? Where can I get me new swords? I don't have much ores left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you leave Loredos area you get all your gear that you left back.

I needed to equip them once I got them back but you should definently have them in your inventory if you've left Loredo after your little talk.

Comment: Loredos is the captain? That didn't work for me. He took everything. I got myself a silver sword but I lost my two-handed.

Comment: Loredo is the commander. If this is not what you meant, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Loredos house entrance has a locked box or locker right outside where the guards are standing - the swords are in there.